# VBA Create a chart from data in an array

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sub that that runs a simulation and creates an array with my data. I'd like to make various charts with this data to understand it, but if possible I'd like to avoid pasting the data on worksheet first, is there a way to make a chart directly from the array?

I can paste the data and work around it, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197014.aspx) gives you the answer.

> ```
> Charts("Chart1").SeriesCollection(1).Values = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19)
> ```